# visibility hidden with animation

Tags: jquery

I want to set `visibility:hidden;` to an element with an animation effect. I got some suggestion of alternative and the following is working for me fine:

```
$(updateSection+' .bubblingG').fadeOut(2000,function(){
                 $(updateSection).before(response.msg);
            });
```

But after fadeOut `display:none;` is set to $(updateSection+' .bubblingG'); But I did not want to set `display:none;` after fadeOut. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be difficult to do it with `visibility`, but you could get the exact same effect if you instead use `opacity`:

```
.bubblingG.hidden {
    opacity:0;

}
.bubblingG {
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 2s linear;
}

$(updateSection+' .bubblingG').addClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var e = $(updateSection+' .bubblingG');
e.css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"})
 .animate({opacity: 0}, 200,function(){
      e.css({visiblity: 'hidden'})
       .css({opacity: 1.0});                                 
  });
```

**Update:**
Animate the **opacity** from **1.0** to **0** (completely transparent), this has the same effect as **fadeOut**. then you can add a callback and set the **visibility:hidden;** yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your own function and **ensure** that the `visibility` property is changed *(note: this is often not necessary! Are you sure you need this?)*, you can do the following with jQuery:

```
$.fadeToHidden = function(selector, duration) {
    $.when(
        $(selector).fadeTo(duration, 0)
    ).done( function(){
        $(selector).css('visibility', 'hidden')
    });
}

$.fadeToVisible = function(selector, duration) {
    $.when(
        $(selector).css('visibility', 'visible')
    ).done( function(){
        $(selector).fadeTo(duration, 1)
    });
}

var visible = 1;
$('#test').click(function() {
    if (visible == 1) {
        visible = 0;
        $.fadeToHidden($('#square'),500);
    } else {
        visible = 1;
        $.fadeToVisible($('#square'),500);
    }
});
```

## [> DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/03quvvdp/)